# MAUI: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()'

Tags: maui

I am getting below exception when running my MAUI application:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference'

**Screenshot:**

[image]

On analysis I found that it is due to the Toast codes.

Below is my code to show a Toast message:

```
public static void ShowToast(string text, ToastDuration duration, double fontSize)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var toast = Toast.Make(text, duration, fontSize);
        await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    });
}
```

I am using `CommunityToolkit.Maui` - 5.3.0 and `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm - 8.2.1` nuget packages for showing toast alerts.

Complete output message:

```
**Java.Lang.NullPointerException:** 'Loading...'

**Java.Lang.NullPointerException:** 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference'

[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] Unhandled Exception from source=AppDomain
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod(JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 12890
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod(String encodedMember, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 151
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(Context context, ICharSequence text, ToastLength duration) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Widget.Toast.cs:line 548
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Alerts.Toast.ShowPlatform(CancellationToken token) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Alerts/Toast/Toast.android.cs:line 48
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Alerts.Toast.Show(CancellationToken token) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Alerts/Toast/Toast.shared.cs:line 80
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Listpm.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<ShowToast>b__0>d.MoveNext() in E:\My Projects\MAUI\listpm-customer-app-maui\ListPM Customer\Utility.cs:line 67
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:line 36
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:line 36
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:line 84
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 22
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:200)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:576)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:563)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:537)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1261)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7311)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:291)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2301)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] 
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:200)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:576)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:563)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:537)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1261)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7311)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:291)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2301)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod(JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 12890
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod(String encodedMember, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 151
[mono-rt]    at Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(Context context, ICharSequence text, ToastLength duration) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Widget.Toast.cs:line 548
[mono-rt]    at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Alerts.Toast.ShowPlatform(CancellationToken token) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Alerts/Toast/Toast.android.cs:line 48
[mono-rt]    at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Alerts.Toast.Show(CancellationToken token) in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Alerts/Toast/Toast.shared.cs:line 80
[mono-rt]    at Listpm.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<ShowToast>b__0>d.MoveNext() in E:\My Projects\MAUI\listpm-customer-app-maui\ListPM Customer\Utility.cs:line 67
[mono-rt] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[mono-rt]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
[mono-rt]    at Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:line 36
[mono-rt]    at Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:line 36
[mono-rt]    at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:line 84
[mono-rt]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 22
[mono-rt]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
[mono-rt] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:200)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:576)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:563)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:537)
[mono-rt]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1261)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7311)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:291)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2301)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
[mono-rt] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:200)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:576)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:563)
[mono-rt]   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:537)
[mono-rt]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1261)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7311)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:291)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2301)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
[mono-rt]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
[mono-rt]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
[mono-rt]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
[mono-rt]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
[mono-rt] 
[RefBase] RefBase: Explicit destruction, weak count = 0 (in 0x7a5cdad278)
```

Comment: I have tested your code about showing a Toast message, there is no error. Can you show the code about calling the ShowToast method and getting the string?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I am calling it from pages and view models like this: Utility.ShowToast("Failed to fetch the access token, please try again later.", ToastDuration.Short, 14);

Comment: I called it in the Button Clicked event and also used CommunityToolkit.Maui - 5.3.0 and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm - 8.2.1 and I target .net 8.0. The Toast showed successfully. Did you try to debug step by step to find which line caused this error?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT On this line the exception is triggering: await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token); I have added the complete output box messages on the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in .net 7.0 and .net 8.0. But you can try to update the CommunityToolkit.Maui package to the last version.

Comment: And did updating the CommunityToolkit.Maui package to the last version work for you?